# Retrieve data through user_Id

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm building an API of a profile. That is my profile controller and I want to retrieve data from the User with the Profile. I'm using `OneToOne` relationships. I want to retrieve data for the single user but as you can see it will give me the data of total users so how can I retrieve of the related user based on id or profile id.

```
profileController extends Controller
{
    public function setting(){
       $profile=User::with('profile')->get();
       return $profile; `enter code here`
    }
}`
```

Comment: single user with specific id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
profileController extends Controller
{
  public function setting(){
    $profile=User::with('profile')->first(); // or find($id);
    return $profile; `enter code here`
  }
}
```

you can use `find()` or `first()` method to get only one user. cek [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

```
profileController extends Controller
{
    public function setting(){
       $profile=User::with('profile')->where('user_id',$user_id)->first();
       return $profile; `enter code here`
    }
```

user where() and first()

Comment: here is a problem with the $user_id how we can get it ...my main question was that @Ankita Tejani

Comment: `Auth::User()->id;` using this @Malikjunaid

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
profileController extends Controller
{
   public function setting(){
     $profile=User::table('profile')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
   return view('profile_page',['profile' => $profile]);

   // or
   return view('profile_page')->with('profile' => $profile);
}
```